# Modify tooltip info of a plotly graph created via ggplotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly

I have this dataset and their respective x and y after I ran my own clustering algorithm and I want a way to analyze it with an interactive view.

`value  max_value  Var1      x  y
  3         6      potato    4  2 
  4         4      banana    3  2 
  5         6      apple     3  1`

I'm trying to use plotly and I'd like to have the plotly viewer show me only the value and max_value on the tooltip/hoverinfo of the respective point. This is what I have so far:

```
gg <- ggplot(test) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x,y =  y, color = Var1), size = 4, alpha = 0.5)
ggplotly(gg)

#alternative
plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~Var1)
```

Is there a way to change the values that the plot show on the tooltip or another package that could help me in this?

Comment: The subtitle ? You mean the tooltips ?

Comment: I mean the box that appears on the points with your cursor goes through the plot. I only can get it to show x, y and var of the point

Comment: Ok. This box is called a "tooltip".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some tooltip info with the `text` aesthetic:

```
library(plotly)
gg <- ggplot(test) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = Var1, 
                 text = paste0("Value: ", value, "</br>Max: ", max_value)), 
             size = 4, alpha = 0.5)
ggplotly(gg)
```

If you want only `value` and `max_value`:

```
gg <- ggplot(test) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = Var1, 
                 text = paste0("Value: ", value, "</br></br>Max: ", max_value)), 
             size = 4, alpha = 0.5)
ggplotly(gg, tooltip = "text")
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to show the max_value in the popup info of plotly:

```
gg <- ggplot(test) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x,y =  y, color = Var1, group = max_value), size = 4, alpha = 0.5)
ggplotly(gg)
```

Now that you have made sure that the `max_value` gets passed to ggplotly, you can control what is shown like this:

```
ggplotly(gg, tooltip = c("x","y","max_value"))
```

Creating the plot directly via the plotly interface is of course another possibility:

```
plot_ly(test, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>% 
  add_trace(x =~x, y =~y, color = ~Var1, 
            text = ~paste0('X Value: ', x, '\nY Value: ', y, '\n max_value: ',     max_value), 
            hoverinfo = 'text')
```

A deeper dive into ggplotly can be found [here](https://blog.cpsievert.me/2018/01/30/learning-improving-ggplotly-geom-sf/)